# Upload .xls file with html input file

Tags: python, excel, google-app-engine, input, webapp2

I can successfully upload a .csv, and a .json file with the following code.  However, when I try to upload a .xls files, the app gets locked up.  What do I need to do to make this work correctly for Excel files?

```
class CreateTeam(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        file = self.request.get('file')  # this line locks up with Excel files
```

My html looks like this...

```
<form method="POST" action="/create_team" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <p>Upload the file</p>
        <input type="file" name="file">
    </div>
</form>
```

I also have some other input fields on the form that are posted with the same submit button.  Is this a MIME type issue.  If so, how do I set the MIME type for just the uploaded file?

Comment: are you getting any more specific errors? Maybe in the Log viewer or something in the browser? Locks up is not very helpful... maybe the file is too big and takes too much time.. did you try to upload a small/different xls file?

Comment: When I say locks up, I mean that the GAE Launcher (Mac) completely freezes and the webpage tab icon spins seemingly endlessly.  The logs stop at that line.  I have to quit the GAE Launcher and restart it each time I hit this line with an Excel file.  My test Excel files only have a few lines.  My latest Excel file has a single word in cell A1 and it also locks things up.

Comment: I've also been trying this with Blobstore and I have the same issue.

Comment: What you don't see above is the `logging.info` line I placed immediately after the `self.request.get()`.  That was the actual culprit.  After removing the logging line, this code worked fine.